# How to add to this list comprehension? Python

Tags: python

Still getting used to using python and wondering, if I wanted to have a count for the number of `x` which are NOT files, how can I change this line?

`teeth = [{"tooth_path": str(x)} for x in p if os.path.isfile(x)]`

I still want `teeth` returning what it currently is, i just want a count with how many are not files.

Comment: `len([x for x in p if not os.path.isfile(x)])`?

Comment: `not` before a condition basically inverts it (so `not False` evaluattes to `True`). Note that `os.path.isfile` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple subtraction:

```
not_teeth_count = len(p) - len(teeth)
```

Comment: in this case, surprisingly obvious, but I think no one saw it.

Comment: man i was being blind! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
p = os.listdir()    
sum([not os.path.isfile(f) for f in p])
```